# How to replace strings in Java (Regex?)

Tags: java, regex, string

Hi and first of all thanks for your help.

I need to perform some data manipulation to a great number of strings in Java.

This is an example of the kind of string I have to modify:

```
<span foreground="blue" weight="bold">accomplish</span> vt, vi, 완수하다, 성취하다, 달성하다, (학문과 기예를) 가르치다  <span foreground="blue" weight="bold">accomplish</span> a, prep, 완성한, 숙달한, 소양(교양)이 있는
```

What I need to do:

delete from the above string all the

```
<span..../span>
```

I will need to take out:

the **a,** the **vt,** the **vi,** the **prep,** and so on.

*Not to take away all chars, but only the specific **a,** the **vt,** the **vi,** the **prep,** and some others.*

EDIT EDIT EDIT
So the expected output would be:

```
    완수하다, 성취하다, 달성하다, (학문과 기예를) 가르치다 완성한, 숙달한, 소양(교양)이 있는
```

I guess I would have to use Regex, but I am absolutely novice to the matter.

Please can somebody give me some help?

Thanks

Comment: `.replace("this","tothis")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`String#replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) with the regex:

```
<span.*?/span>
```

`.replaceAll()` takes a regex as first argument, whereas `.replace()` takes a `String` (a `CharSequence` atually).

Java code:

```
String s = "<span foreground=\"blue\" weight=\"bold\">accomplish</span> vt, vi, 완수하다, 성취하다, 달성하다, (학문과 기예를) 가르치다  <span foreground=\"blue\" weight=\"bold\">accomplish</span> a, prep, 완성한, 숙달한, 소양(교양)이 있는 ";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("<span.*?/span>", ""));
```

Output:

```
vt, vi, 완수하다, 성취하다, 달성하다, (학문과 기예를) 가르치다   a, prep, 완성한, 숙달한, 소양(교양)이 있는
```

#### Update:

If you need to take out more, you can put them in the regex, using the `|` operator. For instance:

```
<span.*?/span>|a,|vt,|vi,|prep,|whateverYouWantDontForgetToEscape
```

Working code:

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("<span.*?/span>|a,|vt,|vi,|prep,", ""));
```

Output:

```
   완수하다, 성취하다, 달성하다, (학문과 기예를) 가르치다     완성한, 숙달한, 소양(교양)이 있는
```

#### Update 2:

Based on the expected output you just posted, you also want to remove duplicated spaces. For that, use this regex:

```
(<span.*?/span>|a,|vt,|vi,|prep,)(\s(?<=\s))*
```

Java code:

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(<span.*?/span>|a,|vt,|vi,|prep,)(\\s(?<=\\s))*", ""));
```

Output:

```
완수하다, 성취하다, 달성하다, (학문과 기예를) 가르치다  완성한, 숙달한, 소양(교양)이 있는
```

Comment: thanks! How do I go about deleting the a, the vt, the vi, the prep, and so on ?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you are saying. What's the rule here? Take everything that is a char? Better: put in your question the **expected output**.

Comment: I updated the answer. See if it works for you. You really should post the expected output, though. If you don't, all we can do is guess.